# Assigning vertex groups in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, vertex-colors

I would like to know if there's a way to assign vertex colors in geometry nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this node setup (this is "just" a proof of concept, that you can change the vertex color itself, it makes no sense though...)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried recreating this setup and it isn't working for me. I'm using Blender 3.0.0. I'm testing with a subdivided cube and using viewport shading set to vertex. Thank you for the response.

Comment: you cannot see vertex colors in viewport shading. and you need a vertex color layer and a material setup like this: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDPPf.png. I just tested it. it works in 3.0

Comment: Got  it. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome